# Python script doesn't recognize 'self' argument in PyQt MainWindow

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm trying to get a PyQt lineEdit widget to place its' contents within a variable in the module 'followup' but for some reason the module does not recognize the PyQt MainWindow as being properly instantiated.

```
    #workbot_main.py
    import gspread
    import os
    import sys
    sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(r"C:\Users\leamy\Desktop\work bot\workbot.py"))
    sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(r"C:\Users\leamy\Desktop\work bot\initial.py"))
    sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(r"C:\Users\leamy\Desktop\work bot\followup.py"))
    import threading
    import followup
    import initial
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
    from PyQt5 import QtCore 
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
    from workbot import *
    import workbot
    #workbot.py is the QTdesigner file containing the widgets,

    
    class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)
        
            followup_start_button = self.ui.followup_start_button 
            followup_start_button.clicked.connect(threads.begin_initialize)
    
    
        def followup_starting_number(self):
            num = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
            return num
    
    
    
        def begin_initialize(self):
            t1 = threading.Thread(target = followup.initialize, args = ())
            t1.start()
    
    threads = Threads()
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
        widget = MainWindow()
        widget.show()
        app.exec_()
```

---

```
    #followup.py
    import workbot_main
    def initialize():
        row_number.number = workbot_main.MainWindow.followup_starting_number()
        print(row_number.number)
```

I get this error

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\leamy\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\leamy\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\leamy\Desktop\work bot\followup.py", line 313, in initialize
    row_number.number = workbot_main.MainWindow.followup_starting_number()
TypeError: followup_starting_number() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I can't understand why it doesn't work.

Edit:

If I try to use

```
row_number.number = workbot_main.widget.followup_starting_number()
```

instead of

```
row_number.number = workbot_main.MainWindow.followup_starting_number()
```

I get this error

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\leamy\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\leamy\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\leamy\Desktop\work bot\followup.py", line 314, in initialize
    row_number.number = workbot_main.widget.followup_starting_number()
AttributeError: module 'workbot_main' has no attribute 'widget'
```

I don't know if that is related.

Comment: Looking at your stack trace, it seems that you are creating/manipulating the GUI from a different thread. You cannot do that. The Qt GUI must run in the main thread. See the [Threading Basics chapter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread) in the Qt Docs. Until you fix that, it is no use trying to fix the issue at hand. They are probably related.

Comment: In the first case you're trying to access a class, while `followup_starting_number` is an *instance* method. In the second you're trying to access an object that doesn't exist in the scope of the imported module, because it's only created in the scope of `__main__`. So: 1. do more thorough research on classes, instances and methods; 2. do not access UI elements from threads, instead eventually initialize the thread *from* the main object, using the data you need.

Comment: How am I supposed to do things like hide/unhide buttons and other dynamic functions  in the UI if I cannot access the UI from an external thread?